# is there a way to autocomplete code when editing go lang code in third package with visual studio code?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

autocomplete working fine in main package .

[working in main package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECbiP.png)

autocomplete can not work rightly when jumping into the third package

[can not work in third package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFgkx.png)

bigxu@T ~> gopls version

golang.org/x/tools/gopls v0.7.0

bigxu@T ~> code --version

1.57.1

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to autocomplete code when editing go lang code in third package with visual studio code?

Yes.

When using `gopls` for IDE integration (which is by now recommended by the VsCode Go Extension so I'll assume that's what you are using) you need to have related projects which you intend to make changes to opened within the same, single workspace in VsCode. Opening them in seperate instances of VsCode will cause issues due to the way the language server operates.

Comment: I opened the main package and the third package in the same,single workspace in VsCode.

Comment: It looks like you are editing packages under `${GOPATH}/pkg/mod/`. These are dependencies downloaded by Go and are pinned to specific versions and should not be edited. You should instead clone the respective repository elsewhere on your disk and edit it there.